# Sabre PassengerDetailsRQ API Payload

Tags: java, php, .net, sabre

What is the issue in my Sabre PassengerDetailsRQ

PassengerDetailsRQ

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.1.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1" IgnoreOnError="true">
    <MiscSegmentSellRQ>`enter code here`
        <MiscSegment DepartureDateTime="11-28" NumberInParty="2" Status="NN" Type="OTH">
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="IST"/>
            <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Code="TK"/>
            </VendorPrefs>
        </MiscSegment>
    </MiscSegmentSellRQ>
    <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" UnmaskCreditCard="true">
        <EndTransactionRQ>
            <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
            <Source ReceivedFrom="YATANGO TESTING"/>
        </EndTransactionRQ>
    </PostProcessing>
    <PriceQuoteInfo>
        <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
        <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1"/>
        <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="1"/>
    </PriceQuoteInfo>
    <SpecialReqDetails>
        <AddRemarkRQ>
            <RemarkInfo>
                <FOP_Remark Type="CASH"/>
            </RemarkInfo>
        </AddRemarkRQ>
        <SpecialServiceRQ>
            <SpecialServiceInfo>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="INFT">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2015-07-25" Gender="F" NameNumber="3.1">
                        <GivenName>Sunil</GivenName>
                        <Surname>Perera</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="true"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </SecureFlight>
            </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </SpecialServiceRQ>
    </SpecialReqDetails>
    <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        <AgencyInfo>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine>YATANGO TRAVEL</AddressLine>
                <CityName>DSD</CityName>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                <PostalCode>76092</PostalCode>
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX"/>
                <StreetNmbr>3150 DDDD DRIVE</StreetNmbr>
            </Address>                    
            <Ticketing TicketType="7T-"/>
        </AgencyInfo>
        <CustomerInfo>
            <ContactNumbers>
                <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A"/>
                <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="972-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H"/>
            </ContactNumbers>
            <Email Address="damayantha@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
            <PersonName  NameNumber="1.1" Infant="false" PassengerType="ADT">
                <GivenName>Sajeewa</GivenName>
                <Surname>Damayantha</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName  NameNumber="2.1" Infant="false" PassengerType="CNN">
                <GivenName>Kamal</GivenName>
                <Surname>Nishantha</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName  NameNumber="3.1" Infant="true" PassengerType="INF">
                <GivenName>Sunil</GivenName>
                <Surname>Perera</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
    </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>

PassengerDetailsRS

<PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1">
    <ns2:ApplicationResults xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
        <ns2:Success timeStamp="2015-08-12T03:55:40.951-05:00"/>
        <ns2:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-08-12T03:55:40.188-05:00">
            <ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
                <ns2:Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.CANNOT ASSOC TO INFANT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</ns2:Message>
                <ns2:Message>4INFTA/DB/25JUL15/F/PERERA/SUNIL-3.1</ns2:Message>
            </ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
        </ns2:Warning>
        <ns2:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-08-12T03:55:40.639-05:00">
            <ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
                <ns2:Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">Â‡INVALID PSGR TYPEÂ‡</ns2:Message>
            </ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
        </ns2:Warning>
        <ns2:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-08-12T03:55:40.773-05:00">
            <ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
                <ns2:Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">INFANT DETAILS REQUIRED IN SSR - ENTER 3INFT/...</ns2:Message>
            </ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
        </ns2:Warning>
    </ns2:ApplicationResults>
    <TravelItineraryReadRS>
        <TravelItinerary>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine>YATANGO TRAVEL</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>3150 DDDD DRIVE</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>DSD, TX US</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>76092</AddressLine>
                </Address>
                <ContactNumbers>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" Phone="817-555-1212-A-1.1" RPH="001"/>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" Phone="972-555-1212-H-1.1" RPH="002"/>
                </ContactNumbers>
                <PaymentInfo>
                    <Payment>
                        <Form RPH="001">
                            <Text>CASH</Text>
                        </Form>
                    </Payment>
                </PaymentInfo>
                <PersonName NameNumber="01.01" PassengerType="ADT" RPH="1" WithInfant="false">
                    <Email>‡DAMAYANTHA@GMAIL.COM‡1.1</Email>
                    <GivenName>SAJEEWA</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DAMAYANTHA</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="02.01" PassengerType="CNN" RPH="2" WithInfant="false">
                    <Email>‡DAMAYANTHA@GMAIL.COM‡1.1</Email>
                    <GivenName>KAMAL</GivenName>
                    <Surname>NISHANTHA</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="03.01" PassengerType="INF" RPH="3" WithInfant="true">
                    <Email>‡DAMAYANTHA@GMAIL.COM‡1.1</Email>
                    <GivenName>SUNIL</GivenName>
                    <Surname>PERERA</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </CustomerInfo>
            <ItineraryInfo>
                <ReservationItems>
                    <Item RPH="1">
                        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="1565" ArrivalDateTime="11-21T17:35" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-11-21T11:40" ElapsedTime="03.55" FlightNumber="1980" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="W" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="IST" Terminal="INTERNATIONAL TERMINAL" TerminalCode="I"/>
                            <Equipment AirEquipType="330"/>
                            <MarketingAirline Code="TK" FlightNumber="1980"/>
                            <Meal Code="M"/>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHR" Terminal="TERMINAL 2" TerminalCode="2"/>
                            <SupplierRef ID="DCTK"/>
                            <UpdatedArrivalTime>11-21T17:35</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                            <UpdatedDepartureTime>11-21T11:40</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                        </FlightSegment>
                    </Item>
                    <Item RPH="2">
                        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="1565" ArrivalDateTime="11-28T15:05" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-11-28T12:55" ElapsedTime="04.10" FlightNumber="1985" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="W" SegmentNumber="0002" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR" Terminal="TERMINAL 2" TerminalCode="2"/>
                            <Equipment AirEquipType="330"/>
                            <MarketingAirline Code="TK" FlightNumber="1985"/>
                            <Meal Code="M"/>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="IST" Terminal="INTERNATIONAL TERMINAL" TerminalCode="I"/>
                            <SupplierRef ID="DCTK"/>
                            <UpdatedArrivalTime>11-28T15:05</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                            <UpdatedDepartureTime>11-28T12:55</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                        </FlightSegment>
                    </Item>
                    <Item RPH="3">
                        <MiscSegment DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="11-28" NumberInParty="02" SegmentNumber="0003" Status="NN" Type="OTH">
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="IST"/>
                            <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
                            <Vendor Code="TK"/>
                        </MiscSegment>
                    </Item>
                </ReservationItems>
                <Ticketing RPH="01" TicketTimeLimit="T-"/>
            </ItineraryInfo>
            <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                <Source PseudoCityCode="4VHH" ReceivedFrom="YATANGO TESTING"/>
            </ItineraryRef>
            <RemarkInfo/>
            <SpecialServiceInfo RPH="001" Type="AFX">
                <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="03.01">I/PERERA/SUNIL</PersonName>
                    <Text>AA INF</Text>
                </Service>
            </SpecialServiceInfo>
            <OpenReservationElements/>
        </TravelItinerary>
    </TravelItineraryReadRS>
</PassengerDetailsRS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.1.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1&quot; IgnoreOnError="true">
     <MiscSegmentSellRQ> 
        <MiscSegment DepartureDateTime="11-28" NumberInParty="3" Status="NN" Type="OTH"> 
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB"/> 
            <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text> 
            <VendorPrefs> 
                <Airline Code="PK"/> 
            </VendorPrefs> 
        </MiscSegment> 
    </MiscSegmentSellRQ> 
    <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" UnmaskCreditCard="true"> 
        <EndTransactionRQ> 
            <EndTransaction Ind="true"/> 
            <Source ReceivedFrom=" TESTING"/> 
        </EndTransactionRQ>
    </PostProcessing> 
    <PriceQuoteInfo> 
        <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/> 
        <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1"/> 
        <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="2"/> 
        <Link NameNumber="4.1" Record="3"/> 
    </PriceQuoteInfo> 
    <SpecialReqDetails> 
        <AddRemarkRQ> 
            <RemarkInfo> 
                <FOP_Remark Type="CASH"/> 
            </RemarkInfo> 
        </AddRemarkRQ> 
        <SpecialServiceRQ> 
            <SpecialServiceInfo> 
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="DOCS"> 
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="1975-07-25" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1"> 
                        <GivenName>CHAN</GivenName> 
                        <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                    </PersonName>
                    <VendorPrefs> 
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs> 
                </SecureFlight> 
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="DOCS"> 
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="1987-07-21" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1"> 
                        <GivenName>WIFE</GivenName> 
                        <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                    </PersonName> 
                    <VendorPrefs> 
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/> 
                    </VendorPrefs> 
                </SecureFlight> 
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="DOCS"> 
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2010-09-08" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1"> 
                        <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName> 
                        <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                    </PersonName> 
                    <VendorPrefs> 
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/> 
                    </VendorPrefs> 
                </SecureFlight> 
                <Service SSR_Code="INFT"> 
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/> 
                        <Text> JOHN/INFANT/25JUN15</Text> 
                        <VendorPrefs> 
                            <Airline Hosted="false"/> 
                        </VendorPrefs>
                </Service> 
            </SpecialServiceInfo> 
        </SpecialServiceRQ> 
    </SpecialReqDetails> 
    <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ> 
        <AgencyInfo> 
            <Address> 
                <AddressLine>YATANGO TRAVEL</AddressLine> 
                <CityName>DSD</CityName> 
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode> 
                <PostalCode>76092</PostalCode> 
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX"/> 
                <StreetNmbr>3150 DDDD DRIVE</StreetNmbr> 
            </Address>
            <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/> 
        </AgencyInfo> 
            <CustomerInfo> 
                <ContactNumbers> 
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A"/> 
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="SYD" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="972-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H"/> 
                </ContactNumbers> 
                <Email Address="damayantha@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/> 
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" > 
                    <GivenName>CHAN</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>JOHN</Surname>
                </PersonName> 
                <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" > 
                    <GivenName>WIFE</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                </PersonName> 
                <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" NameReference="C04" > 
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                </PersonName> 
                <PersonName NameNumber="4.1" Infant="true" NameReference="I02" > 
                    <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>JOHN</Surname> 
                </PersonName> 
            </CustomerInfo> 
    </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ> 
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```